# Lines count in a CSV file differs than count of iteration in a while loop. Perl

Tags: perl, csv, while-loop, iteration

I have a certain doubt:
I have a CSV file with 71162 lines (rows) of text.

To process each line I apply simple Perl code:

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
        #some code
    $count++;
}
print $count;
```

After loop the $count is equal to 71158. 
What happened with 7 missing lines? How to detect which lines I've missed?

thx

Comment: Perhaps somewhere in the "some code" section, you're doing a "next" and iterating to the next line before incrementing the counter?

Comment: Also, you may have changed the record separator variable.

Comment: Yes, I have initialized $count to 0. I've opened a file in Gedit, I scrolled down and I checked number of the last line. The option "wrap text" in Gedit is disabled. "some code" does not have any suspicious code. To test the code,  I've put just "print NEWFILE "$line;" instead of "some code", to obtain the same input file. Number of iteration is still 71158 but the number of lines in OUT file is 71165. Separator is unchanged, it's a semicolon.

Comment: What makes you think perl has the wrong count? Why not Gedit? Tried another editor, or even `wc -l file`?

Comment: Last line if blank can be missed.But needs your **#somecode** section to understand what you have done there.

Comment: @TLP has right!! Gedit shows too much lines. "wc -l file" command and Libre Office displays corrcet number of lines.
I had no idea that Gedit can cheat on me!!
thx guys

Answer (score 2):

So I guess the answer is:

What makes you think perl has the wrong count? Why not Gedit? Tried another editor, or `wc -l file`?

To which the answer was: Perl was right! Gedit was wrong.

Perl will always tell you exactly what you told it to tell you.